# Create a lambda function in runtime lisp

Tags: lambda, lisp

Let's say i have a function "create-lambda" defined like this:

```
(defun create-lambda(x y)
    (lambda(z) (let ((foo (some-other-function z y))) (if (= x foo) T))))
```

If i call this function, like this:

```
(create-lambda 2 3)
```

It will return:

```
#<FUNCTION :LAMBDA (Z) (LET ((FOO (SOME-OTHER-FUNCTION Z Y))) (IF (= X FOO) T))>
```

What i want is, to return this:

```
#<FUNCTION :LAMBDA (Z) (LET ((FOO (SOME-OTHER-FUNCTION Z 3))) (IF (= 2 FOO) T))>
```

Is this possible?

Comment: The printed form of lambda functions, e.g., `#<FUNCTION :LAMBDA (Z) (LET ((FOO (SOME-OTHER-FUNCTION Z Y))) (IF (= X FOO) T))>` is not standardized.  In this case, since the value of `x` and `y` can't be changed (unless they've been globally declared special), there should be no observable difference.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter for the end result since `x` and `y` are bound in the lexical scope to `2` and `3`. You are saying you don't want:

```lisp
(let ((x 2) (y 3))
  (let ((foo (some-other-function z y))) 
    (if (= x foo) T)))
```

But you want:

```lisp
(let ((foo (some-other-function z 3))) 
  (if (= 2 foo) T))
```

But I can't tell the difference. Can you?
Anyway. You can [coerce](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_coerce.htm) any data structure to be a function like this:

```lisp
(defun create-lambda (x y)
  (coerce `(lambda(z) 
             (let ((foo (some-other-function z ,y)))
               (when (= ,x foo) T))) 
          'function))
```

Or you can make create-lambda a macro:

```lisp
(defmacro create-lambda (x y)
  `(lambda(z) 
     (let ((foo (some-other-function z ,y)))
          (when (= ,x foo) T))))
```

The differences between these are easy to spot if you call it with side effects`(create-lambda (print 3) (print 4))`. In the first the side effects will happen right away since functions evaluate all their arguments while the macro will just replace the whole thing for x and y and the side effect happen at call time.